# Colored to Grayscale loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an issue with this, when my page loads, it needs to be turned from grayscale to colored (Code below), but then i need it to swap to grayscale and colored continuosly.

HTML:

```
<img src="images/main.jpg" id="mainimg" />
```

CSS:

```
#mainimg{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition : -webkit-filter 3500ms linear;
    -moz-transition : -moz-filter 3500ms linear;
    transition : filter 3500ms linear;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('#mainimg').on('transitionend', function () {
    $(this).css({
        "webkitFilter" : "none",
        "mozFilter" : "none",
        "filter" : "none"
    });
}).css({
    "webkitFilter" : "grayscale(0%)",
    "mozFilter" : "grayscale(0%)",
    "filter" : "grayscale(0%)"
});

});
```

Another problem is that IE and Opera aren't doing the transition, it's not the main problem, because i'm looking for it right now, but if it's easy for someone to help with it, I would be thankful.

(i'm not used to JQuery, but i'm trying to learn it, if you guys think JQuery would be better, post it)
Thanks in advance and sorry if i'm being 'newbie'!

Comment: making it a class and toggling the class with javascript would probable be the better approach if you are just using css transition/animation

Comment: Actually, I haven't tought about that, I guess it would bring less headache than switching the filters values. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I think I know what the issue you were having was now, though.  You were using quotes for `webkitFilter` et al.  If you use quotes, use the exact name (e.g. `"-webkit-filter"`); otherwise, use no quotes if you know the correct javascript attribute (e.g. `webkitFilter : "grayscale(0%)"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going the transition route, I would suggest using a class instead of trying to set the values manually

```
#mainimg{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition : -webkit-filter 3500ms linear;
    -moz-transition : -moz-filter 3500ms linear;
    transition : filter 3500ms linear;
}

#mainimg.transition {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Then just set the class via your favorite method

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#mainimg').addClass('transition');
}
```

If you want back and forth transition, use keyframes

Comment: I need the back and forth transition, so i used the keyframe, as you said: 
@-webkit-keyframes grayscale-anim{
 from {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}
 to{-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);}
}
It worked well on the browsers, the only one i need to try is on IE10, because keyframes are not supported on newer versions

Well, thanks, it helped a lot!